# Map and Sort Methods for component in React?

Tags: reactjs

Relatively new to React and trying to sort the mapped prop `nearbyRestaurants` alphabetically by `place.name`. Is there a way I can chain the sort method to the end of the map method to alphabetize the list?

```
export default function RestaurantList({nearbyRestaurants}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li className="list-header">Restaurants</li>

        {nearbyRestaurants.map((place) => (
          <div>
            <li>
              <div>{place.name}</div>
              <div>{place.vicinity}</div>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `sort` then `map` is all you should need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array before mapping it.

```js
function sortAlphabetically(a,b){
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
}

export default function RestaurantList({nearbyRestaurants}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li className="list-header">Restaurants</li>

        {nearbyRestaurants.sort(sortAlphabetically).map((place) => (
          <div>
            <li>
              <div>{place.name}</div>
              <div>{place.vicinity}</div>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```